# WPF - Send mouse wheel messages to a Frame/WebBrowser control

Tags: wpf, webbrowser-control, mousewheel

I'm hosting some web content in a WPF app using the WebBrowser control (or Frame, havent' decided yet).  There are some external influences that I'd like to use to simulate mouse wheel behavior in the web content.  Is there a way for my WPF app to send mouse messages to the WebBrowser control, with a Delta (scroll) value that I specify?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will not find anything simpler try this. Get [WebBrowser window handle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.hwndhost.handle.aspx), and [SendMessage()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx) [WM_MOUSEWHEEL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms645617(VS.85).aspx) to it...

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion - I'll use that as a backup.